# Flow when user is purchasing a in-app purchase in iOS and has no payment data

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a subscription in-app purchase in my app, and I'm using iOS StoreKit Framework.

If a user has no payment data, and he is trying to subscribe, the delegate will return .failed, and after this user inserts his payment data, StoreKit  will return .purchased?

Or it will wait until user cancels or fill his payment data in order to return .failed or .purchased?

Answer (score 1):

Once you receive a `.failed` you should finish that transaction. The user will have to initiate a new purchase after updating their payment info and you will get a new `SKPayment`.

Comment: Do you mean this process creates two different transactions for the same purchase? Makes sense. Is there a kind of documentation where can I read about it? I found something here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6431